# How to setup Single Sign On for IFS

Tags: ibm-midrange

Does anyone know how Windows/IBM i determines if Kerberos should be used when access an IFS folder via Windows File Explorer (e.g. \MYIBMI)?  I've our IBM i EIM configured to do Single Sign On using our Windows network login.  For the ACS 5250 session, I simply change the connection to use the "Use Kerberos authentication; do not prompt" option and voila Single Sign On is used.  But when accessing IFS via Windows explorer, I've some users saying that Single Sign On works fine also and some users saying that they are still being prompted for IBM i user id and password.  I couldn't quite figure what controls whether kerberos should be used when access IFS via windows file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue with those users that are still being prompted for user ID and password when accessing IFS was caused by their IBM i credentials were saved in the Windows credential manager.  So, below is what we did to get sso working for them:
-> Open Windows Credential Manager
-> Under the Windows Credential tab, delete the IBM i credential.